# Problema com array em javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando usar o conteúdo de uma variável como nome de um Array, mas está retornando uma letra do conteúdo dessa variável.

Exemplo:

```
var posicaoArray = 2;
var nomeArray = "frutas";
var frutas = new Array();
frutas [0] = "Banana";
frutas [1] = "Melancia";
frutas [2] = "Maçã";
frutas [3] = "Laranja";
document.write(nomeArray[posicaoArray]);
```

Irá retornar a letra " u ", letra número 2 da palavra "frutas" se contarmos a partir de 0, ao em vez de aparecer "maçã".

Porque acontece isso?

Comment: Isso está no escopo global? Se estiver, pode usar `window[nomeArray][posicaoArray]`.

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou: `console.log(eval(nomeArray)[posicaoArray]);`. Desconheço se é a melhor maneira, mas é uma alternativa.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft funcionou! muito obrigado,ajudou bastante.

Comment: Nesse caso, acredito que para fins de estudo, não tem problema uso do `eval()`, mas é importante a leitura de vários artigos sobre ele (inclusive li vários agora há pouco), para que nunca o use de forma errada ou de formas que comprometam sua aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

Isso que você está tentando fazer está errado, o resultado apresentado é totalmente previsível. Imagine a seguinte variável:

```
var palavra = "carro";
```

Em JavaScript, tudo é um objeto, logo, podemos pegar partes da palavra normalmente usando um array. Para pegar a letra "c", usamos o *index* 0, já que é o primeiro. Exemplo:

```js
var palavra = "carro";
document.body.innerHTML += palavra[0];
```

Ou seja, você está pegando posições da sua *string*, e não do seu array. Você pode guardar tudo em um array multidimensional. O primeiro *index* será o nome da sua variável, e os segundo *index* será uma cópia do outro *array*. Exemplo:

```js
var posicaoArray = 2;
var nomeArray = "frutas";
var frutas = new Array();
frutas [0] = "Banana";
frutas [1] = "Melancia";
frutas [2] = "Maçã";
frutas [3] = "Laranja";

var data = {};
data[nomeArray] = frutas;

document.body.innerHTML += data[nomeArray][posicaoArray];
```